# SQL Server 2008 installation issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had installed SQL Server 2008 and received a error now after about 7 months that the evaluation period has expired; without any previous notifications. I searched online and found that I needed to make a change in the registry and reinstall SQL Server 2008. I am trying to do upgrade install and getting the error:

> Rule "SQL Server Analysis Services
>   Upgrade Edition Validation Check"
>   failed Sql server analysis services
>   evaluation edition can be upgraded
>   only to standard, enterprise or
>   developer edition.

My question is that if I decide to do a fresh new install, do I need to remove the older installed version and what happens to my databases in that case?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Your own databases will certainly not be touched by uninstalling and/or reinstalling SQL Server (this however doesn't apply to the system databases like `master`, `model` and so forth - those are part of the system, obviously)

Comment: Thank you. So is it necessary to uninstall old version first or will sql server do that with the fresh install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an uninstall will leave your data in tact. You'd have to attach the databases to the new server install.

Comment: Do i need to remove the old installation or does the server 2008 installation center take care of that

Comment: You would need to run the uninstall. In your case a new named install (in case your current install is the default) would also work. In that situation you could backup from the old and restore to the new, or detach the databases and then move (or copy)the files to the new instance's data directory and attach to that one.

Comment: Thanks by the way I unable to access SSMS now since the evaluation period expired so I will continue with the fresh install